# My forum is not updating the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update my table by using the fourm :-

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for Message.new do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :To %>
      <%= f.email_field :to, class: 'form-control' %>


       <%= f.label :Subject %>
      <%= f.text_field :subject, class: 'form-control' %>

       <%= f.label :Content %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control' %>



     <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my controller I have done :-

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(user_params)
    redirect_to root_url

  end


   def user_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:to, :subject, :content)

    end
```

But when i check my Table, there is no update .

Where am i going wrong ?
My table have 2 more extra attributes , but i am not filling them up with the forum .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.new` just builds the new object, you need to actually `save` it to persist it to the database.

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(user_params)
  @message.save!
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Comment: or as variant
@message = Message.create(user_params)